relative address instead of absolute address in the relocation table
In the context of compiler optimization and linker behavior, I'm trying to understand the implications of using relative addresses instead of absolute addresses in the relocation table during the compilation and linking process.
My question is: Why would using relative addresses instead of absolute addresses in the relocation table potentially improve the runtime performance of the program?
Edit:
I noticed that using relative addresses makes fetching quicker because they occupy less memory. However, after fetching, converting relative addresses to absolute ones adds extra processing time. So, I'm wondering why relative addressing is still seen as an improvement despite this additional overhead.

absolute address require more memory/larger binary size, where relative addresses would be smaller, so instead of a jump to 0x992130 it could jump relative from its current executing address to 0x2130 if you are already at location 0x99000 (numbers aren't valid but it makes my point)

@X3R0
but i need to make the calculation 0x99000 + 0x2130 and it takes times too. why its better?

usually the compiler does the calculations while building the binary, see your assembly compiler tools configurations for more details

relative addressing mode is handled at compile time not at runtime. so only overhead is during compilation

also the CPU supports relative addressign mode and absolute mode. the actual jmp instructions have aboslute and relative jmp instructions, to handle each and the CPU uses those instruction variations to know what to do when given the address

@X3R0 "relative addressing mode is handled at compile time not at runtime" - not entirely true really, nowadays compilers by default produce position independent executables that still need to be relocated at startup by the system loader.

@MarcoBonelli correct, for example in new version of windows (8, 8.1, 10 and 11) they introduced random memory allocation, which loads the program into split parts at various memory locations. this was introduced for security concerns  to ensure that each application's memory integerty is maintained.

@MarcoBonelli The compiler now days still does the relative/abosule mode, but for windows there are differences compared to an elf binary made for linux/unix systems
